# Specifying l18n config in build file

Tags: internationalization, requirejs, locale, r.js

I am using the l18n bundle with requirejs.  In dev mode I want to pull the locale from local storage.  In prod mode I want to do the same.  `mainConfig.js`:

```
config: {
    i18n: {
        locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || null
    }
}
```

But at build time I do not care about locale, (infact r.js throws an error when parsing the config file).  But I can't see any option to overwrite it ([r.js/example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L49)).

How can I specify locale like `locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || null` in `mainConfig.js`, but no locale at build when `buildConfig.js` specifies `mainConfigFile: mainConfig.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: don't put the locale spec in `mainConfig.js` in the first place, but make another call to `require.config` with the locale information.  Configs get merged.  Be sure to match the context if applicable.